# Cut It Up! (then find a phrase)

Tags: logical-deduction, word, visual, geometry

This is a "sorry for messing up yesterday's clues" puzzle.

For each shape below, divide along grid-lines into identical pieces (rotation and reflection allowed). The first shape has **3** pieces, and the second has **6**. I tried to make the grids look pretty :)

Then find the hidden message, which definitely does not describe you, dear solver. To decode it you will need these numbers: 137211214 and 2136412. Good luck!

[image: grid shapes]

If no one has solved this in a day, I'll start posting hints. Also - is there a better tag than [word](/questions/tagged/word) for finding a phrase?

EDIT: I accidentally swapped the # of pieces. It's 3 and 6, updated now

Smaller hint:

> Each number corresponds to a word, and each word is 5 letters

Medium hint:

> Break the numbers up with spaces

Comment: Are the black squares included? Also a bit confused for the second as there are 47/49 squares with and without the black squares, but neither of those are divisible by 3... (word is fine btw :) )

Comment: Black squares are not included. There are 30/48 squares without black

Comment: Sorry, turns out I can't count :P

Comment: I made a mistake though - just edited it to be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add the cherry to the top of @BeastlyGerbil's cake, the final answer - which the OP says "definitely does not describe you, dear solver" - is:

> **SMART ALECK**

To find this, realise that the two tesselating shapes are:

> An '**F**' and a '**Y**'. These are the **6th** and **25th** letters of the English alphabet, respectively.
>
>  [image]
>  <sup>*Image courtesy of @BeastlyGerbil's answer [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98799/60644) - go upvote!*</sup>

Taking the two strings provided by the OP - 137211214 and 2136412 - we can:

> Split these into numbers conveniently in the range of 1-26. Although there are many possibilities for these choices, only one arrangement will lead us to the answer: **13-7-21-12-14** and **2-13-6-4-12**.
>
>  Convert these into letters using A1Z26, to get **MGULN** and **BMFDL**. Now recalling the 'F' and 'Y' tile shapes, apply rot-6 (since F is the 6th letter) to the first string and rot-25 (since Y is the 25th letter) to the second to get the answer, **SMART ALECK**.
>
>  Since a 'Smart Aleck' is "a person who is irritating because they behave as if they know everything", it is rather a relief that the OP does not hold us in that regard!

Comment: Good job! Maybe the second hint was a little too much...

Comment: @bobble To be honest, I'd already sussed Hint 2 was required, so I didn't really need it. Hint 1 with the word lengths was the more vital of the two to me...

Comment: Reminder to self: don't assume that your solver's brains will do that same logic as yours.

Answer (score 6):

### Partial answer: Shapes found!

The grid is cut like so:

> [image]

The shapes:

> Spell 'f' and 'y' but I'm not sure what that means.
>
> I got these by counting the number of squares and dividing by the number of shapes so I knew the squares per shape, and then looking at the edges and possible recurring shapes.

Not sure what the numbers mean just yet but think A1Z26...

Comment: Good job! I figured that the cutting would be the easy part... using the numbers requires an 'ah hah!' moment. Also, rot13(vg'f abg n w) Edit: also rot13(vg'f abg n g). I guess the shape wasn't good enough... it is a rot13(ybjrepnfr s)

Comment: I've found you the final answer (see my contributed answer [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98833/60644)) - feel free to add it to yours for a complete solution (I insist this time!) :-)

Comment: @Stiv no I insist! :P I simply found some shapes, that’s the easy part here! The cipher is much harder to find, all I did really was find 2 letters :)

Comment: Well, here we go again! :-) I'll link to your answer and borrow the image then... (Ever thought of just merging our accounts, so we can find *complete* solutions all in one go?!) (JOKE)

Comment: @Stiv see, OP agrees that you did the hard work! :P Also don’t think it would be fair if we merged, I’d probably only contribute 20% of the combined answers! :P

Comment: Well, [when this all gets sorted out, I think you and me should get an apartment together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAHNW_avrVM)...! (again, JOKE)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I've been wondering, which of the shapes was harder to find? I expected the y to be more difficult since there were more. But apparently I'm a terrible judge of difficulty.

Comment: @bobble don’t worry, judging the difficulty of you own puzzle is in my opinion the hardest thing about puzzle making here :) I think that I got them both in about the same amount of time, interestingly I didn’t even realise they were letters until I posted the answer and tried to explain the shape of them. I got the first from the 3 ‘prongs’ and working out how to link that with wrapping round the black squares, and for the second it was a mixture of the bottom of blue and wrapping around the black squares again. Bit of trial and error, but I’d say they were as hard as each other :)

Comment: Yeah, the black squares were there for 1) making it easier and 2) because it's **hard** to tile letters